# Is there a bug in Safari with linear gradients? I get unexpected results

Tags: css, safari

When I use the following code, which I'm seeing in essentially the same form in lots of tutorials:

```
body { 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 
    0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000), to(#fff)); 
}
```

I get this result (Safari 5.0.5):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJo6c.jpg

multiple repeated 8px gradients.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

The screenshot above is from a page with absolutely no content in the body. Apparently with Safari, the body is 8px high if it's empty? And the gradient also displays over the whole viewport, even if only applied to the body ... ?

I would love to have an explanation, but anyway, the fix is this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

because for some reason `body { height: 100%; }` isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change from `from()` and `to()` to using color-stops?

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #000),
    color-stop(1, #FFF)
);
```

It shouldn't be repeating unless you used `-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient`.

Resources

- [Gradients in Safari version before 5.1](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH10-SW34)
- [Gradients in Safari version 5.1 and higher](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html)

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, I'm afraid. But thanks for your answer because it helped me figure out the problem.